# How can I process a multi line string one line at a time in perl with use strict in place?

Tags: perl, string, multiline, filehandle

I'm trying to figure out the proper PBP approved way to process a multi line string one line at a time.  Many Perl coders suggest treating the multi line string as a filehandle, which works fine unless you have "use strict" in your script.  Then you get a warning from the compiler about not being able to use a string as a symbol while strict refs is in use.

Here's a simple working example of the problem:

```
#use strict;
use warnings; 

my $return = `dir`;
my $ResultsHandle = "";
my $matchLines = "";
my $resultLine = "";
open $ResultsHandle, '<', \$return;
while (defined ($resultLine = <$ResultsHandle>)) {
    if ($resultLine =~ m/joe/) {
        $matchLines = $matchLines . "\t" . $resultLine;
    }
}
close($ResultsHandle);
print "Original string: \n$return\n";
print "Found these matching lines: \n$matchLines\n";
```

Notice that the "use strict" line is commented out.  When I run this script without use strict, I get what I want and expect:

```
Original string: 
 Volume in drive D has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 50D3-54A6

 Directory of D:\Documents and Settings\username\My Documents\Eclipse\myTestProject

09/18/2009  11:38 AM    <DIR>          .
09/18/2009  11:38 AM    <DIR>          ..
09/18/2009  11:36 AM               394 .project
09/18/2009  11:37 AM                 0 joe.txt
09/18/2009  11:37 AM                 0 joey.txt
09/18/2009  11:38 AM                 0 kurt.txt
09/18/2009  11:43 AM               497 main.pl
09/18/2009  11:38 AM                 0 shane.txt
               6 File(s)            891 bytes
               2 Dir(s)   6,656,188,416 bytes free

Found these matching lines: 
    09/18/2009  11:37 AM                 0 joe.txt
    09/18/2009  11:37 AM                 0 joey.txt
```

Here's the problem, though.  When I uncomment the "use strict" line, I get the following warning or error from Perl:

```
Can't use string ("") as a symbol ref while "strict refs" in use at D:/Documents and Settings/username/My Documents/Eclipse/myTestProject/main.pl line 8.
```

Line 8 is the "open $ResultsHandle, '<', \$return;" line, by the way.  So since Perl Best Practices requires me to use strict, how does PBP expect me to process a multi line string one line at a time?  Any suggestions from the SO community?

Thanks!

Comment: If you do want to talk about best practices, I suggest you take a look at all your variable initialization, at the way you define variables like in oldfashioned C (at the top), and your use of backticks for something that can easily be achieved by Perl itself.

Comment: Thanks, Manni.  The directory content retrieval was just for demonstration purposes.  My actual program actually calls another program and processes its output.  And the old fashioned variable initialization is something I need to work more on.  But I often cut & paste from old scripts and this is what I get.  :-)   I'm trying to do better, though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't initialise `$ResultsHandle`:

```
use strict;
use warnings; 

my $return = `dir`;
my $ResultsHandle;  # <-- leave undefined
my $matchLines = "";
my $resultLine = "";
open $ResultsHandle, '<', \$return;
while (defined ($resultLine = <$ResultsHandle>)) {
    if ($resultLine =~ m/joe/) {
        $matchLines = $matchLines . "\t" . $resultLine;
    }
}
close($ResultsHandle);
print "Original string: \n$return\n";
print "Found these matching lines: \n$matchLines\n";
```

If you leave `$ResultsHandle` undefined before the `open()`, it will be filled in with a reference to the file handle.  Because you were setting it to a string, `open()` presumed that it was supposed to be a symbolic reference to a variable instead --- not allowed under `use strict`.

Comment: Wow.  Thanks!  Shows how little I know about Perl!  I guess I thought I had to initialize it to SOMETHING.  Guess I was wrong.  Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: Also shows that I don't understand "strict" at all.  I've been just trying to please the compiler and the Perl Critic module both without fully understanding all the messages they've both been generating.

Comment: Another way to think about it: `open()` initialises `$ResultsHandle` for you, *if it's not already been initialised*. `use strict` disallows things which can be useful occasionally, but more often cause trouble.

Answer (score 7):

The more succinct PBP way is to use [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) like so:

```
open my $ResultsHandle, '<', \$return;
```

This eliminates the need for that earlier "my $Resultshandle;" declaration and avoids incurring that *strict* warning that you ran into.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use a regexp as an iterator:

```
my $data = q{Hello
This
Is
A
Test};

while( $data =~ /(.+)$/mg) {
    print "line is '$1'\n";
}
```

This is slightly less convoluted compared to using a filehandle that represents a string.

Answer (score 3):

Convert the multi-line string into a list of single line strings with `split`:

```
my @resultLines = split /\n/, $result;     #   or  /\r\n/ for Windows?
foreach my $resultLine (@resultLines) {
    if ($resultLine =~ m/joe/) {
        $matchLines
            = $matchLines . "\t" 
                 . $resultLine . "\n";  # put \n or \r\n back on the end
    }
}
```

Comment: if you use '\n' as line separator, it will not assign \n characters to $resultLine variable. better use  split /^/m, $result , it will assign whole line with line ending. Be patient, last line not allways have got end of line characters.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
my $ResultsHandle = "";
```

to

```
my $ResultsHandle;
```

Answer (score 0):

Open a filehandle using a pipe from "dir" command.

E.g.

```
open my $FOO, "dir|" or die "Can not run 'dir': $!";
```

Comment: Indeed. If "dir" is a must, go for the pipe. But I'd rather use readdir or a simple glob.

Answer (score 0):

Better result with split can be done by:

```
my $result="LINE1
line2
linE3
";
#attention, /^/m allows properly operate on multiline string using regex
#and ^ is character empty begin all lines
foreach my $resultLine (split /^/m, $result) {
    print $resultline;  #withount '\n' because it have got
    #some checks & operations
}
```