# How to process a multiline string line at a time

Tags: perl, string

I'd like to get a substring between two delimiters (regexes) from a string. I want to use this:

```
while (<>) {
  if (/START/../END/) {
    next if /START/ || /END/;
    print;
  }
}
```

But this works on lines of stdin. I'd like make it work on lines of a string. How?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I process a multi line string one line at a time in perl with use strict in place?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445426/how-can-i-process-a-multi-line-string-one-line-at-a-time-in-perl-with-use-strict)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you mean you want to process a string that already contains multiple lines then use split:

```
foreach (split(/\n/, $str)) {
  if (/START/../END/) {
    next if /START/ || /END/;
    print;
  }
}
```

Comment: My lisper sense is telling me that you missed a closing paren.

Comment: but in which variable would you catch the splitted single line ?

Comment: @AbhishekSagar the variable is Perl's default string variable, $_

Answer (score 7):

Simply:

```
my ($between) = $string =~ /START(.*?)END/s;
```

Alternatively, read from the string:

```
use 5.010;
open my $string_fh, "<", \$string or die "Couldn't open in-memory file: $!";
while ( <$string_fh> ) {
    ...
```

Comment: While this is a cleaner way to do this, it doesn't solve my string-splitting problem.

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to get multiline data into a string. If you want it to happen automatically while reading input, you'll want to set `$/` (probably to '' for paragraphs or undef for the whole file) to allow you to read more than one line at a time.

see "multiline" section @ [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq6.html)