# Creating a multi-line variable in Perl

Tags: perl, variables

Following my other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597683/processing-text-inside-variable-before-writing-it-into-file)..

I have the following piece of code where I read the contents of a webpage line by line, trying to match a certain pattern and if matched, write it to a file:

```
foreach my $line (split qr/\R/, $mech->content) {
    if ($line=~ m/t\/([A-Z]+)/){
        print $fileHandle "$1\n";
    }
}
```

I wonder whether it possible to append the matching lines to another multi-line variable and write it to a file only when the loop is finished.

The reason I want it to be that way is because I want to use the following subroutine to save data to a file, rather than doing it directly:

```
writeToFile("fileName.tmp","path",data);
```

This is a subroutine I wrote, which apart of just saving the data in a file, also checks the following:

1. Whether the specified path already exists (and creates it if needed)
2. If the file already exist on disk, compare it to the one which is about to be written (and write it only in case the files are different)

So if I'll be able to create this additional variable, I will have one less file to write to a disk.

Comment: I will remove [tag:algorithm] from it. I guess there won't be any magic in this (yet I know nothing about [tag:perl])

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can do it by string concatenation, inside your loop you simply replace print with

   ```
   $data .= "$1\n"; 
   # Same as $data = $data . "$1\n";
   ```
2. Or use the magic of Perl's `map` to build the multiline string, without having either a loop or an `if`:

   ```
   my $data = join "", 
                   map { /t\/([A-Z]+)/ ? "$1\n" : "" } 
                   split(qr/\R/, $mech->content);
   ```
3. Or, you don't even have to go through the pain of splitting and joining.

   Simply treat your multiline string as a single string (`/g` modifier lets the regex match again and again), and replace your entire loop with just 3 lines:

   ```
   my $data = $mech->content();
   $data =~ s/t\/([A-Z]+)/$1\n/g;
   writeToFile("fileName.tmp", "path", $data);
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. Could you please explain how the output of the expression (number 3) can be stored to a variable / written do a file?

Comment: @EugeneS - see my update. "Output" of expression 3 is just the original variable itself - the regex substitutes "in-place" in Perl.

Comment: And #3, ladies and gentlemen, is why Perl is Good.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple - you can append characters by using `.=` operator (which is comboned assignment (`=`) and concatenation (`.`):

```
my $data = "";
while (my $line = ...) {
    ...
    $data .= $line . "\n";
}
writeToFile("fileName.tmp", "path", $data);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please explain why the last `.` is needed (after `$line`)?

Comment: @EugeneS - in his code, it's needed as concatenation operator. Personally, in our company I always enforce a style which uses interpolation over concatenation, e.g. `"$line\n"` is better than `$line . "\n"` in my experience, style wise

Comment: @DVK So the `.` just concatenates lines?

Comment: @EugeneS - . concatenates any strings. `$line . "\n"` simply concatenates the string with newline.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace

```
open(my $fileHandle, ...) or ...;

...

   print $fileHandle "$1\n";
```

with

```
my $data = '';

...

   $data .= "$1\n";
```

to append the output to a string instead of sending it to a file handle.